# OCaml parser for :: case

Tags: ocaml, yacc, ocamlyacc

I'm having trouble with associativity. For some reason my = operator has higher precedence than my :: operator

So for instance, if I have

> "1::[] = []"

in as a string, I would get

> 1 = []::[]

as my expression instead of

> [1] = []

If my string is "1::2::[] = []"

I thought I it would parse it into exp1 EQ exp2, then from then on it will parse exp1 and exp2. But it is parsing as exp1 COLONCOLON exp2 instead

```
.
.
.

%nonassoc LET FUN IF
%left OR
%left AND
%left EQ NE LT LE
%right SEMI COLONCOLON
%left PLUS MINUS
%left MUL DIV
%left APP

.
.
.

exp4:
    | exp4 EQ exp9                { Bin ($1,Eq,$3) }
    | exp4 NE exp9                { Bin ($1,Ne,$3) }
    | exp4 LT exp9                { Bin ($1,Lt,$3) }
    | exp4 LE exp9                { Bin ($1,Le,$3) }
    | exp9                        { $1 }

exp9:
    | exp COLONCOLON exp9         { Bin ($1,Cons,$3) }
    | inner                       { $1 }

.
.
.
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  Your grammar has `EQ` with higher precedence than `COLONCOLON` and that is how it is parsing things by your descriptions.  Is that what you want?  If so, what is the question?

Comment: Actually, the order of precedence is from lower to higher with ocamlyacc: see Section [12.4.2  Declarations](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/lexyacc.html#sec279) from the documentation : "All symbols on the same line are given the same precedence. They have higher precedence than symbols declared before in a %left, %right or %nonassoc line. They have lower precedence than symbols declared after in a %left, %right or %nonassoc line."

Comment: What is the rule for `exp`? Have you tried writing a small self contained grammar for expressions, to test out your idea?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might have multiple expression rules (`exp`, `exp1`, `exp2`, ... `exp9`), in which case the precedence of operations is determined by the interrelation of those rules (which rule expands to which other rule), and the `%left`/`%right` declarations are largely irrelevant.

The yacc precedence rules are only used to resolve shift/reduce conflicts, and if your grammar doesn't have shift/reduce conflicts (having resolved the ambiguity by using multiple rules), the precedence levels will have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Rules aren't just applied like functions, so you can't refactor your grammar in a set of rules, at least with `ocamlyacc`. You can try to use `menhir`, that allows such refactoring by inlining rules (`%inline` directive).

To enable `menhir` you need to install it, and pass an option `-use-menhir` to `ocamlbuild`, if you're using it.

Comment: Good advice: I tried out `menhir` on a small grammar with the `exp4` and `exp9` rules as in the question, and it resulted in warnings telling that the precedences were ineffective. Using that tool instead of the stock `ocamlyacc` is helpful.